Using Keywords QuickPart in Word Header & Footer. Text uses //; when SAVE, Word changes // to /. How do I stop if from doing that?
I use the Keywords QuickPart as a container for my Header and Footer Text.
In that container, I might type ProjectName//ProjectLocation.
When I SAVE the document, and Word redisplays, it comes back with one / instead of the original two //.
If I SAVE again, it will hold ... HOWEVER, if I SAVE AS (having changed the Project Name and/or Location, it misbehaves again.
HOW do I keep it from changing the // to /??
I thought it might be AutoCorrect ... but even after adding several versions of what I need, it's not AutoCorrect.
I'm not a developer and don't use Visual Basic ... but one of my coworkers is very good with VB.
So, if the answer lies with VB, please provide the details and I'll pass it along to him.
Many thanks.
I tried setting up entries in AutoCorrect ... and that didn't solve the problem

Your question is off-topic for Stack Overflow which is a forum for specific questions about programming. I recommend posting on SuperUser, or Microsoft Office Forums instead
